# how to find the index of a character in a string from specific position

Tags: ios, string, swift

I know how to find an index of a character like the following:

```
func indexOfCharacter(myString:String, char: Character) -> Int {
        if let idx = find(myString, char) {
            return distance(self.startIndex, idx)
        }else{
            return -1;
        }

    }
```

How can I look for an index after a specific position ?

example:
myString="abcdabcd"

I would like to get the index of the second 'd' = 7

```
indexOfCharacter(myString,character : 'd',fromIndex: 4);
```

any help ?

Comment: Use the [`substringFromIndex`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW22) function.

Comment: he is asked in Swift, not in ObjectiveC

Comment: At Ramshad. Would this be faster in objective c then in swift ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
func indexOfCharacter(myString:String, char: Character,fromIndex: Int) -> Int {

    let sub = myString.substringFromIndex(advance(myString.startIndex, fromIndex))
    if let idx = find(sub, char) {
        return distance(sub.startIndex, idx) + fromIndex
    }else{
        return -1
    }

}

let myString = "abcdabcd"

indexOfCharacter(myString, "d", 4)   // 7
```

update: **Xcode 7.3 • Swift 2.2**

```
func indexOfCharacter(myString:String, char: Character, fromIndex: Int) -> Int {

    let sub = myString.substringFromIndex(myString.startIndex.advancedBy(fromIndex))
    if let idx = sub.characters.indexOf(char){
        return sub.startIndex.distanceTo(idx) + fromIndex
    }else{
        return -1
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Question is perfectly answered. Do you know in which direction I should go, when I would like to be more performant in getting the index (sorry for the bad english) objective-c ?

Comment: @mcfly soft Swift is as fast as objective c, no need to worry about it